# Virtual scrolling option for combobox

Tags: wpf, combobox, ui-virtualization

I need to display the visible items into view instead of displays all the rows in combo box control.
While scrolling that, we need to load next visible items.

How can I do that? Also, how can I ensure whether it is loaded in virtually?

Sample example:

```
public List<string> items = new List<string>();
public MainWindow()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  DataContext = this;
  for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
  {
    items.Add("item"+ i.ToString());
  }
  combo.ItemsSource = items;
}
```

Front end:

```
<Grid>
   <StackPanel>
      <ComboBox x:Name="combo" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,10" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" />
    </StackPanel>
 </Grid>
```

After refer link:

```
   <ComboBox x:Name="combo" Height="100" Width="150" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
               ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,10" 
               VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode ="Recycling" >
         <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
              <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                   <VirtualizingStackPanel IsVirtualizing="True"
                                      VirtualizationMode="Recycling" />
              </ItemsPanelTemplate>
         </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ComboBox>
```

Comment: have you tried using VirtualizingStackPanel?

Comment: Yes i am also try with <ComboBox x:Name="combo" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,10" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing ="True"/>  Then How can i ensure whether it is loading as virtual?

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/virtualization-wpf check this site. Also to ensure, try to get any ye to load container using ItemsContainerGenerator.

some thing like .. _comboBox.ItemsContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem({_unloadedmodelitem})

Comment: That link is not helpful for me.Can you please explain your point?

Comment: in that link they are using VirtualizingStackPanel to ItemsPanel, which can be set for ComboBox as well.

Comment: Yes i had tried but i have seen no improvement. code has been attached above.

Comment: I think there may be some confusion on what you are trying to achieve. Are you trying to just show like 3 items in the with a smaller drop down instead of the default amount of "x" items WPF shows? The virtualization part should be working.

Comment: Yes @Tronald, I try to show the 3 items, How to do it?

Comment: I am trying to show some items(Ex:3 items) in combo box, while i am scrolling that scroll bar need to show the next visible items(Next 3 items).

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple thing you will need to do. First thing, lets clean up your ComboBox and Subscribe to the `ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged` event. Many of your ComboBox properties are already set by default so we can remove them. We can also set the `MaxDropDownHeight` to specify how many items to show at once. Here's how it should look.

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="combo" ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged="combo_ScrollChanged" MaxDropDownHeight="70" Height="100" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,10">
     <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
           <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
           </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
 </ComboBox>
```

Next, we need to handle the scroll event in order to skip items by 3 while also preventing recursion when we force the scrollviewer to change.

```
    bool scrolling = false;//Used to prevent recursion
    private void combo_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
    {         
        ComboBox cb = (ComboBox)sender; //Get the sending ComboBox
        ScrollViewer sv = cb.Template.FindName("DropDownScrollViewer", cb) as ScrollViewer; //Find the Comboxes ScrollViewr

        //If scrolling down
        if (e.VerticalChange < 0 && !scrolling)
        {
            scrolling = true; //Set to true to prevent recursion
            sv.ScrollToVerticalOffset(e.VerticalOffset - 2);//Scroll an extra 2 spaces up
            return; //Exit 

        }
        //If scrolling up
        if (e.VerticalChange > 0 && !scrolling)
        {
            scrolling = true; //Set to true to prevent recursion              
            sv.ScrollToVerticalOffset(e.VerticalOffset + 2);//Scroll an extra 2 spaces down
            return; //Exit
        }
        if (scrolling) { scrolling = false; } //Set to false to allow offsets
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Tronald I have understand your code.Here you visible the next items while scrolling scroll bar. But what my need is, i have 1 million records and show that data via combo box control. Here i have applied control template and data template for that combo box.So it will take long time and UI will be crashed.

Comment: So need to apply that data template for visible items only, remaining items are loaded while scroll bar changed.How to achieve this?